# Laravel caching large number of queries

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, caching

I got an ecommerce site that has up to 1million products and the site is in many regions. Each product page has around 10-15 queries to DB, stuff like get product by url, get product category and get product format etc. Currenly im using laravel file-based caching and im not caching anything on product page.

The problem is product pages are also targets for various crawlers/bots meaning a large number of queries made to DB. Also if I cache a product page say for 1hour its unlikely that will be hit in that time period since those bots target all of the pages. Also since I have different regions (different domains) meaning the number of pages is timed by count of regions (5-10).

So I'm out of ideas how to cache this. I thought about caching all those queries forever (without time limit) and changing the cache when something about product changes. Is this the way to go? Does laravel create a cache file for each query that is being cached? If yes then the number of files could become a problem.

Also I thought about using redis. But I think i would run out of memory when caching that many keys? Any idea how should I go about caching this? Thanks in advance.

## Edit1:

Thought about html caching with redis. So that I would cache for example product price and its html. Any ides how much memory do I need to cache lets say 10-20million keys with some html as their value?

Comment: You can use redis.

Answer (score 1):

There is a laravel package that caches queries.

https://github.com/dwightwatson/rememberable

```
User::first()->remember(1440)->posts()->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Some caching ideas:

nginx cache the entire HTML page if people are not logged in.

get 4 more VPS and put nothing but memcache on each one and memcache all your queries.  Keep adding more servers until you have enough memory to cache all the querires.

get 4 more VPS and put mysql on each and use all available memory for query caching.  Use sharding (not master slave) to route requests for certain products to certain machines.  keep adding machines until all data is held in query caches

rewrite the system so that it doesn't require caching to function at acceptable speeds.  Caching works best when it is used for greater throughput, not for increasing speed.